# ALTER TABLE,Error Code: 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created database and table with a MySQLWorkBench.But I want to have column with number 1995

```
ALTER TABLE ldp ADD COLUMN '1995' INT(128);
```

The response is

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1995' INT(128)' at line 1
```

Comment: Use backticks instead of single quotes around `1995`.

Answer (score 2):

Column names cannot begin with a number in MySQL unless they are escaped.  The way to escape a column name in MySQL is to use backticks, not single quotes.  Single quotes denote a string literal.  Hence the following should work:

```
ALTER TABLE ldp ADD COLUMN `1995` INT(128);
```

But I find it odd to use a column name which starts with a number.  You might want to call it something else beginning with a letter.